# Show Chrome browser in Top Browsers analytics report

Tags: 2010, web-analytics

The 'Top Browsers' web analytics report appears to report Safari and Chrome browsers as same browser. Is there any way to report on Chrome separately?

Perhaps updating the browser definition files or similar?

Comment: Google Analytics clearly distinguishes Chrome from Safari

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no.  The code that identifies the browsers doesn't specifically look from Chrome (and there is no outside way to modify how that works).  Since Chrome uses WebKit and Safari in its User Agent, that's what SharePoint thinks it is.

If you need more granular browser reporting, you would need to either write the data collection yourself or use a third-party solution.